# WinForms.ReportViewer to display customerized item?

Tags: wpf, winforms, reportviewer

I am designing a reporting page using WinForms.ReportViewer and only process the data locally. It means we want to display some information from objects that we designed. For example, we have our own classes for date and time. However, in the report page this date and time information can not be displayed correctly (shows #ERROR). Is there any way to tell it how to show our information? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the newer ReportViewer versions, MS has introduced an [error](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553592/accessing-nested-objects-in-data-source-of-local-report-does-not-function) that disables the possibility for navigation within objecs.
They have corrected the error with the last [service pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2010/10/27/nested-objects-in-local-mode.aspx) a little and if your objects support serialization, now navigation may work.

For my newer projects built with report viewer 2010, I have started to write a wrapper for each object/entity I have to render. I started with this during the time, no fix was available and now I'm very comfortable with this pattern. In the first moment, it gives a little more of work, but it has given me great flexibility and left my code clean. And if one day I dont have the patience to work further with report viewer anymore, it will make it easy to move my projects to another reporting engine.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate which one is proper to us. Actually we use customized class in other WPF pages to parse the date and time information, I will see if I can integrate it.

Comment: @user944213: If this answer has helped you, please click on the checkmark under the voting buttons to mark this answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @tete: It's on the left side of my answer, under big zero. Its a gray checkmark.